# how to prevent node.js application from terminated for unhandled exception in setInterval?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node.js application terminated for unhanded exception in setInterval. I try to fix it by process.on('uncaughtException', ..) and domain approaches (see below codes). Application still was terminated although the exception was handled.

```
function f () {
    throw Error('have error')
}
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
    console.log("process.on uncaughtException")
})

var d = require('domain').create();
d.on('error',function(err){
   console.log("domain.on error")
})

d.run(function(){
   setInterval(f, 1000)
})
// program terminated and output is: domain.on error
```

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_warning_don_t_ignore_errors

Comment: @jgillich's link is very important. Domains are not meant to avoid crashes, they are meant as a final line to clean up after errors and properly close down. You'd generally use a process monitor to start up a new process if one dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program terminated because there was nothing else to process after setInterval().  In nodejs doc example, it creates the the server and bind the port to it.  That's what keeps the application running.  Here is the example from the doc:

```
var d = require('domain').create();
d.on('error', function(er) {
  // The error won't crash the process, but what it does is worse!
  // Though we've prevented abrupt process restarting, we are leaking
  // resources like crazy if this ever happens.
  // This is no better than process.on('uncaughtException')!
  console.log('error, but oh well', er.message);
});
d.run(function() {
  require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    setInterval(f, 1000);
  }).listen(8888);
});
```

Then if you point your browser to localhost:8888, the app is not terminated

Comment: The question is about throwing exceptions. `setInterval` timers will keep the process open just like a server will.

Comment: setInterval() will not keep the app running.  When nodejs reaches the end it'll just exit unless you bind it to the port and listen like in the example

Comment: Do you mean if there is an exception? A program with only a setInterval won't just close.

Comment: The exception in f() will cause setInterval() to stop but if you're running as a server, it keeps the app running.  Try put console.log() instead of throw Error(), setInterval() keeps running

Comment: Yeah okay. Sorry, from the way you phrased it as terminating because there was nothing after it, it sounded like you thought a setInterval wouldn't keep the application open at all. Now I see you were saying that throwing an exception in a timer clears the timer out of the event loop, so node won't stay open.